# How to reduce the number of DB connections

Tags: java, database, oracle

In my project we have 800 automated test cases and for every test case we follow below approach
1.Open a DB connection
2.Run the query based on the test case
3.Close the DB connection

Above step repeats for 800 times as we have 800 cases, is there any other alternate way to reduce the number of DB open and close connections?

Actually we tried like this open DB connection once then run all the test cases ( i.e running the queries) then closing the connection at last but we are seeing issues in this approach,So please suggest on this.

Comment: Are you using a connectionpool?

Comment: DBCP is your friend

Comment: Check on how to use a connection pool. It works perfectly in such situations by  reusing the connection from pool

Comment: use singleton approach to get connection..

Comment: @Srivenu that's for amateurs.

Answer (score -1):

I would advise to define Spring configuration/context that contains at least single bean, i.e. database connection pool, and use this Spring configuration/context in every test that requires database connection.

You can use any connection pool you like (like [c3p0](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) or [Apache DBCP](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/)).

Since Spring won't close context between tests (unless you tell him to do it with `@DirtiesContext`), connection pool will be shared between those tests. But you will be able to define different settings for different tests and connection will be correctly closed after test suite completed.

Another (more ugly, but simple) option is to use some static instance of connection pool shared between all tests. I.e. define some class with static reference to connection pool and use it in all tests as a replacement for direct connection opening. Connections will be closed on JVM exit then.